# Excel Function to handle a variable amount of variables and ranges and then input them into R

Tags: r, excel, vba

I am trying to write a function where I input as many variables and ranges as I want and it will send it to R using RExcel.

Currently I can just do a single var entry at a time using the function `RPut` such as `=RPut("X1",A2:A16)` which puts in the `A2:A16` range into R as the variable `X1`.

Ideally I want to write something such as `VariableToR("x1", A2:A16,"x2", B2:B16,...)` for all the variables I might be using at a time. Any thought on how I can write a function using a loop to do this?

I am guessing something of the format:

```
Function VariableToR(ParamArray Var() As String, ParamArray Ranges() As Range)
Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(Var) To UBound(Var)
    RPut("Var(i)",Range(i))
Next
End Function
```

Edit: Tim would something such as this be more correct?

```
Function VariableToR(ParamArray Var() As Variant)
Dim i As Integer
Dim i2 As Integer
For i = LBound(Var) To UBound(Var)
i2 = i + 1
Active.Cell.Formula = "=RPut("Var(i)", Range(i2))"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
Next
End Function
```

How do I loop through the formula entry though to put in the values from Var()?

Comment: You can only have one ParamArray argument, and if there are multiple arguments it must be the last one. If you want to do what you describe then use a single ParamArray and loop over it treating first member as a string, second as Range, and so on.

Comment: I didn't know that. I did an edit to my question to respond to what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a non-R example using a single ParamArray:

```
Function VariableToR(ParamArray arr() As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer, v As String

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) Step 2
        v = v & arr(i) & ":" & arr(i + 1).Address() & vbLf
    Next

    VariableToR = v
End Function
```

EDIT: populating worksheet cells with a formula.  You cannot do this directly from a worksheet formula though: a UDF isn't allowed to modify the workbook - it can only return a value.

```
Sub Tester()
    VariableToR "x1", Range("A1:A3"), "x2", Range("C1:C3")
End Sub

Sub VariableToR(ParamArray arr() As Variant)
        Dim i As Integer, c As Range

        Set c = ActiveCell

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) Step 2

            c.Formula = "=RPut(""" & arr(i) & """ , " & _
                               arr(i + 1).Address() & ")"

            Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim any thought on how to do it by inserting the RPut function multiple times down a sheet as that seems to me to be the easiest solution? I posted up some general syntax in my question.